# Javascript onClick change background picture of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, onclick, jquery-events

My ultimate goal is to change the background of a div through clicking on the sampla picture.

First I wrote this:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('sp').style.background="url('/assets/castle.png')"">...<a>
```

but it didn't work. I noticed that the problem was usage of multiple " and '. So put the function into a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pic="";
    function showP(pic) { document.getElementById('sp').style.background='url(pic)';};
</script>

<a onclick="showP(/assets/castle.png)"><img src="/assets/castle.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
```

As supposed by seeing `/assets` dir, this is a rails app. I also tried o use jQuery selectors like `$("#sp").css()` or dropping the variable altogether and trying the function as:

```
function showp1() { document.getElementById('sp').style.cssText='background: transparent url(/assets/castle.png) no-repeat 0 0;'}
```

to try out solutions proposed in questions with similar titles but none did work. Whatever I try, on the html source, the portion **showP(/assets/castle.png)"** below is marked red:

```
<a onclick="showP(/assets/castle.png)"><img src="/assets/castle.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest making, and then linking to, a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your use-case (in brief) and problem, and also incorporating the [tag:jquery] tag, as you seem to be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid putting JS in your HTML code. Use unobtrusive event listeners. They are very easy in jQuery:

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
    $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000)');
})
```

[See this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/LPUgF/3/)

Comment: I tried every one's solution and none of them worked. I tried on jsFiddle with jQuery 1.7.1 and Brendan's and your solutions worked there. As Brendan's code is heavier, I prefer yours. Can you check the page at [the supposed page](http://futbolsendromu.com/sign_up) and tell me the problem with the code? By checking the page source you can verify that jQuery 1.7.1 is loaded and another jQuery code is working.

Comment: Running jQuery version on your page is reporting as 1.4.2. Try this: `$('img').click(function() { $('#sp').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')'); });`

Comment: I deleted the jQuery.min1.4.2 file and tried both of your solutions. They didn't work. I prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frNcw/1/). It's not working either. Can you check that? I added the whole javascript code with the ...first-and-second-carousel.. stuff because I thought that or the syntax of the javascript might be the reason.

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/frNcw/7/). That just wasn't working because there was an error thrown at `.jc()` before the listener was attached. Make sure you are checking your JS Console for errors.

Comment: You are right on that. I separated the javascript functions into a user.js file and firebug didn't show any errors. Maybe you noticed that the page source still marks the "javascript:;"" part red. Any idea, what may cause this error? by the way, sorry for the 10-15 min delays but I'm trying the solutions out in jsFiddle and my page.

Comment: You could try `<a href="javascript:void(0);"` and see if it likes that better but it shouldn't be necessary and I don't see why it would be causing any problems. Worse case scenario, go to: `<a href="#"` it'll make the page jump to the top when you click it but it is definitely valid.

Comment: # does not cause the page to jump to the top. So maybe link is not functioning. The source is `<li style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;" class="jc-item jc-item-h><a href="#" id="castle"><img src="/assets/castle.png" width="50px" height="50px" /></a></li>`. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer since you showed all possible ways with jQuery. I'd be glad if sth comes up to your mind about the link problem.

Comment: That all looks valid to me. It might be an issue with the browser. I would run the page through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to determine whether it's the code or the browser at fault.

Comment: Just to inform, after changing the <img /> tag to <img></img>, the code worked. Don't know the reason but nevermind:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showP(pic) { 
        document.getElementById('sp').style.background = 'url(' + pic + ')';
    };
</script>

<a onclick="showP('/assets/castle.png')">
    <im  src="/assets/castle.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
</a>
```

You needed to pass a string to the `showP` function in the `onclick` handler, which should be in quotes.  You're passing a string into the function, which is in the `pic` variable being passed into the function.  You want that string variable's value to be concatenated with the URL rule for the background style.

Comment: Thank you for making me recall the use of " + pic + " but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the background image URL does not require quotes. Try:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('sp').style.background='url(/assets/castle.png)'">...<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you do seem to have an issue with quotes. You can check out my [working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYYg/1/).