# change background-image to image file in html 5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using html5 for drag and drop image, my code is still running normally. But, i can only drop image to background-image in dropbox, not image file. So, i can't get and insert image into database. This is my code:

### script

```
    var holder = document.getElementById('leftbox'), state = document.getElementById('status');   
    if ( typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') {
        state.className = 'fail';
    } else {
        state.className = 'success';
        state.innerHTML = 'Drop files here'
    }

    holder.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = '';
        return false;
    };
    holder.ondragend = function() {
        this.className = '';
        return false;
    };
    holder.ondrop = function(e) {
        this.className = '';
        e.preventDefault();

        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            console.log(event.target);
            holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
        };
        console.log(file);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);    
        return false;
    };
```

### HTML

```
<div class="medium-4 medium-centered columns">
        <p id="status"></p>
        <div id="leftbox"></div>
    </div>
```

What should i do to change `holder.style.background` to image file? please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

[javascript onClick change background picture of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732523/javascript-onclick-change-background-picture-of-div)

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function() { $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000)'); })
```